# How to update IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition at the moment I have IIS 6 installed.

I need to update IIS to version 7.5.

Using Server Management under Roles, I can see `Web Server IIS Installed`. Using Web Platform Installer I can see only IIS 7.5 Express.

**Question:**

How can I upgrade to IIS 7.5? (normal version - not Express) Could you please provide some instructions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIS on Windows is version-locked. This means that 1 version of IIS ships with a specific version of Windows and that's it. If you want to change IIS, you need to change your version of Windows.

This matrix might help

```
IIS 5   -   Windows 2000 Server
IIS 6   -   Windows Server 2003
IIS 7   -   Windows Server 2008
IIS 7.5 -   Windows Server 2008 R2
IIS 8   -   Windows Server 2012
```

Generally speaking IIS Express isn't installed on a server, because there's no need. If you're working with an existing Windows 2008 R2 server that has the IIS (Web Server) role installed, you're working with IIS 7.5

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for your answer? Specifically, the "IIS on Windows is version-locked". I just can't find any reference for this on the "great" MSDN website.

Answer (score 5):

There is no IIS6 on Windows Server 2008R2, and it is not possible to install it there. So you already have IIS 7.5.

IIS 7.5 express is an application, not a service, it does not show up in Server Management, both Express and the full version can be installed at the same time. There is usually no reason to install Express on a server. It's used to development on workstations.